# jqGrid column align does not work when there is formatter for ui-icon

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid column model as shown below. The align property works fine when there is no `formatter`. When I added a formatter for displaying `ui-icon`, it is not aligning to the right (last column in the screenshot). What is the best jqGrid approach to correct the alignment?

**jqGrid colModel**

```
colModel: [
             { name: 'StockSymbol', key: true,  width: 150 , align: "right"},
             { name: 'StockName', width: 250, align: "right" },
             { name: 'VariationPercent',  width: 150, align: "right" },
             { name: 'GamesCount',  width: 100, align: "right" },
             { name: 'UsersCount',width: 100, align: "right" },
             { name: 'TotalPurchasedQty',  width: 150, align: "right" },
             {
                name: 'Create', index: 'StockSymbol', width: 120, align: "right",
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus app-custom-button-create"  title="Create"></span>';
                 }
             }
           ],
```

**Sreenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is very easy. Class `ui-icon` uses CSS property `display: block`, but the CSS property `text-align: right`, which will be set by jqGrid on `<td>` will be not applied on blocks. To fix the problem you can for example modify the `formatter` to the following

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus app-custom-button-create"' +
        ' style="display:inline-block;" title="Create"></span>';
}
```

which changes `display: block` to `display: inline-block`.